# IBM DB2 running a query from one database to other in db2

Tags: db2

Is there a way I can run a query from one database in DB2 to another database in DB2?

For example I have two databases:

1. Sample
2. Target

I will write a query in target and I will call the table which is there in sample database. But, it should execute it in target database.

Comment: Federation is the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you need to use Federation.
You will catalog a table from *sample* database in *target* database. You will have a nickname in *target* database, and you can do any query on this table (nickname) as it were local. DB2 will call the other database, and retrieve the data.
However, the real execution is in *sample* database, the only thing is that you call execution from *target* database.

When you use different types of databases, you use InfoSphere Information Server 8.7 in order to connect to Oracle, SQL server, etc.
For DB2 and Informix it used to be included (you have to check it)

For more information http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004122.html

Comment: Federation is used in the context where different databases come into picture but here,we have only one database that is db2.....

Comment: Federation in DB2 is used to query other data sources. They can be databases, files, etc. The question was how to query on DB2 database from another DB2 database, and federation could be used.